# R - Reading from a column with URLS in and pasting the page titles in another column

Tags: r, url

Is it possible for R to read URLS in a column and then paste the page title in another column. Asking for a lot I know but is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

```r
library(xml2)
url <- "http://www.sapijaszko.net"
html <- read_html(url)
title <- xml_text(xml_find_all(html, ".//title"))
df <- data.frame("url" = url, "title" = title)
df
#>                         url          title
#> 1 http://www.sapijaszko.net sapijaszko.net
```

Now, you can create your list of URLs, get the titles, and compose a data frame.

<sup>Created on 2022-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is great how do i point it to the correct column to read the url, say I have a list of urls in column B and i want it to copy the titles in to column A?

Comment: Also how come we are doing this twice ?  What does these parts refer to    url <- "http://www.sapijaszko.net"
html <- read_html("https://www.bbc.co.uk/") sorry for so many questions I am new to R all help greatly appreciated

Comment: See my answer below, @user2822467

Answer (score 0):

Just wrape it within function, then execute for your list of URLs.

Let load 2 libraries, which we will use in our example.

```
library(xml2)   # library allows to manipulate XML/HTML documents
library(dplyr)  # this library allows wrangling data.frames
```

Lets create a list of URL's, and put it in data frame

```
urls <- data.frame(url = c("https://cran.r-project.org/",
  "https://stackoverflow.com/"))
```

Right now `urls` is an data.frame object with one column called `url`. For details you can run `str(urls)`.

Lets create a function, which returns the title of web page. Our unction will take an URL as an argument, fetch the web page content, then will search for title and return it. Our function usestwo other functions: `read_html()` and `xml_text()` from `xml2` package. `read_html()` in fact reads the content of web page, `xml_text()` allows to search the page for specific text, in our case `title`.

```
getTitle <- function(url) {
  html <- read_html(url) 
  title <- xml_text(xml_find_all(html, ".//title"))
return(title)
}
```

Now, we will apply our function to our list of URLs, and create another column with the titles. We will use `mutate()` function from `dplyr` package for column creation, we will use `lapply()` for applying our own function to the URLs.

```
urls |>
  mutate(title = lapply(url, getTitle), .before = "url")
```

As result, we will get an output simillar to this one:

```
                                                           title                         url
1                             The Comprehensive R Archive Network https://cran.r-project.org/
2 Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers  https://stackoverflow.com/
```

So, the whole code:

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
urls <- data.frame(url = c("https://cran.r-project.org/", "https://stackoverflow.com/"))

getTitle <- function(url) {
  html <- read_html(url)
  title <- xml_text(xml_find_all(html, ".//title"))
return(title)
}
urls |>
  mutate(title = lapply(url, getTitle), .before = "url")
```

For details of any function you can run `?function_name`, like `?lapply`.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help however when i run this i get the following error message Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `title`.
i `title = lapply(url, getTitle)`.
x URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Comment: should i be edittng this somewhere i have just been pasting it directly in getTitle <- function(url) {
  html <- read_html(url)
  title <- xml_text(xml_find_all(html, ".//title"))
  return(title)
}